# onclick show/hide next table rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

onclick get button show/hide next rows between the clicked button and next button.
How to display these rows as hidden first and after that i can switch between show and hide them. if it is possible with vanilla JavaScript and CSS.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button>show/hide</button> A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button>show/hide</button> AA</td>
    <td>BB</td>
    <td>CC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button>show/hide</button> AAA</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
    <td>CCC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *if it is possible with vanilla javascript* - if you don't want [tag:jquery] then don't tag [tag:jquery]...

Comment: so a solution requested in vanilla javascript yet jQuery wins the day..

Comment: thx for  answers it was helpful, jquery and javascript doesn't matter. I said if possible  in vanilla javascript. I did not say vanilla  javascript only.

Comment: don't worry - I was laughing when I typed that... perfectly fine. So long as you have an answer and options - good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `vanilla` javascript you can utilise the `indexOf` method to find where the table-row element containing the clicked button is and then iterating over `N` rows after and toggling the display state.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  /* create an array from the nodelist so that `indexOf` can be used */
  let col=[...document.querySelectorAll('tr')];
  
  /* find the parent table row of the invoking button */
  let tr=this.parentNode.parentNode;
  
  /* find which table row in the array was the event source */
  let index=col.indexOf( tr ) + 1;
  
  /* process the next N records/rows */
  for( let i=index; i < index + 2; i++ ){
    col[i].style.display=col[i].style.display=='table-row' || col[i].style.display=='' ? 'none' : 'table-row'
  }
}))
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr{display:table-row}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><button>show/hide</button> A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test 1</td>
            <td>test 1</td>
            <td>test 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button>show/hide</button> AA</td>
            <td>BB</td>
            <td>CC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test 1</td>
            <td>test 1</td>
            <td>test 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button>show/hide</button> AAA</td>
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>CCC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test 1</td>
            <td>test 1</td>
            <td>test 1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The key here to achieve what you want is to use `.nextUntil("tr:has(button)")`

as in:

```
$('table button').click(function() {
  var n = $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil("tr:has(button)");
  n.toggle()
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('table button').click(function() {
  var n = $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil("tr:has(button)");
  n.toggle()
})
```

```css
  table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button>show/hide</button> A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button>show/hide</button> AA</td>
    <td>BB</td>
    <td>CC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button>show/hide</button> AAA</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
    <td>CCC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>test 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is set for two table rows. It doesn't work for more than two rows. Only 2 rows; hides and shows. `for( let i=index; i < index + 2; i++ )` where a variable should be used for the number 2. In other words, how many rows will be affected must be determined in advance.